# C# Authorisation form between forms

Tags: c#, forms

I am creating a Database Application using C# (WPF) and MySQL. My problem is certain forms such as a form allowing a user to delete and/or recreate tables should require a password (can be hardcoded).

I have tried several things already and researched as much as possible but I am yet to have the perfect solution. The closest I have got so far is creating a form named "SecurityCheck" which takes a string when called, which would be the destination form. The Security Check form then uses a switch statement to decide which form to open if the user enters the correct password. This works however ideally I would like to pass the form as an arguement eliminating the need for a switch statement?

The other problem with this method is I can't figure out how to set the destination forms owner to the original calling form.

Ideally the security checking form would act as a generic bridge between any two forms I wish to open but my limited knowledge of C# is crippling me.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Don't hard code passwords. It will take someone about 30 seconds with a tool like RedGate's .NET Reflector or Telerik's JustDecompile to extract the password.

Comment: @john thanks for your advice, I will store them within the database instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I know your mean right, you need a method like this to open securityCheck form before showing your specified form:

```
private void OpenFormWithAuthentication(Form destination)
{
    SecurityCheck secForm = new SecurityCheck();
    secForm.ShowDialog();
    if(secForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.Ok)
    {
        destination.Show();
    }
}
```

In your SecurityCheck form, you should assign proper value to the result of form:

```
/* SecurityCheck form*/
if(Authenticate(username,password))
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;
else
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ali. This is what I was after, I was thinking along the same lines however I couldn't find a way to send the Form across, I didn't think of making it first. Two strange things I had to change was Form to Window and DialogResult == DialogResult.Ok to DialogResult == true.